# How to close a connection with a firebird database

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, firebird, firebird-.net-provider

I'm developing a project using asp.net c# webforms framework 4.5, and I did a connection test on Firebird database, but when I close this connection it isn't closing, I used the following code to do it:

```
string conDDNS;
FbConnection conexaoDDNS;

protected void Abrir_Fechar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.conDDNS = "DRIVER=InterBase/Firebird(r) driver;User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=localhost:C:/AdCom/ADCOM.FDB";

        this.conexaoDDNS = new FbConnection(conDDNS);
        this.conexaoDDNS.Open();
        ListItem item = new ListItem("Conexão aberta");
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item);

        this.conexaoDDNS.Dispose();
        this.conexaoDDNS.Close();
        ListItem item2 = new ListItem("Conexão fechada");
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item2);

    }
    catch (Exception erro)
    {
        ListItem item = new ListItem(erro.ToString());
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }

}
```

I have already used the `.Close()` and `.Dispose()` command but it didn't work.

When I did this debugging I realized that when it pass by `.Open()`command it opens the connection, that is alright. But when it pass by `.Close()` command the connection is still open on database.

To know the number of connections opened on database I'm using the following command:

```sql
select * FROM MON$ATTACHMENTS
```

Comment: You should call Close() before you call Dispose(). You could also use a Using-Statement instead of calling Dispose manually. Are you sure your check for open connections, always is the current state or maybe its updated a bit delayed? How long the connection stays open after you called close?

Comment: The Firebird .NET provider has a built-in connection pool; I believe it is enabled by default, add `Pooling=false` to the connection string to disable it. Also make sure you start a new transaction when querying `MON$ATTACHMENTS`. The content of monitoring tables is 'frozen' inside a single transaction.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it worked adding `Pooling = false`, thank you so much !

Answer (score 10):

The Firebird .NET provider has a built-in connection pool and it is enabled by default. You can add `Pooling=false` to the connection string to disable it. However in a lot of cases a connection pool is a good thing (it saves the time of having to open a connection), so make sure you really need to disable it.

Calling `FbConnection.ClearPool(connection)` or `FbConnection.ClearAllPools()` should close currently open connections in the pool.

Also make sure you start a new transaction when querying `MON$ATTACHMENTS`. The content of monitoring tables is 'frozen' inside a single transaction.